# Async PHP requests

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads, reactphp

So, I want to create an asynchronous web service in PHP. Why? Because I've a nice async front-end, but Chrome will block my requests if I have more than 6 active TCP connections. Of course I have read some similar questions like:

- [Async requests in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457282/async-requests-in-php)
- [Multiple PHP Requests Crashing Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624043/multiple-php-requests-crashing-page)

but these don't cover my question.

I installed `pthreads` with the intention that I would be able to make multiple requests in different threads so that my PHP wasn't blocking other requests(in my situation I start eg. a long process and I want to be able to poll if the process is still busy or not).

PHPReact seems to be a nice library(non-blocking I/O, async) but this won't work either(still sync).

Am I missing something or is this nowadays still not possible in PHP?

```
class Example{
    private $url;   
    function __construct($url){
        $this->url = $url;
        echo 'pooooof request to ' . $this->url . ' sent <br />';
        $request = new Request($this->url);     
        $request->start();
    }
}

class Request extends Thread{
    private $url;   
    function __construct($url){
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    function run(){
        // execute curl, multi_curl, file_get_contents but every request is sync
    }
}

new Example('https://gtmetrix.com/why-is-my-page-slow.html');
new Example('http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php');
new Example('https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20file%20get%20contents');
```

The ideal situation would be to make use of callbacks.

ps. I have seen some servers(like Node.js) that are providing this functionality, but I prefer a native approach. When this is not possible I'm really thinking of switching to Python, Java, Scala or some other language that supports async.

Comment: You are surely missing something, but the question is unclear ... it sounds like you want to handle *incoming* requests asynchronously, yet the example shows you trying to spawn simultaneous *outgoing* requests.

Comment: @Narf I want to handle both asynchronously. Just to explain my current situation: I've a JavaScript front-end, some kind of a PHP interface/controller to communicate with Java webservices. So my front-end will send a request to my PHP controller and this controller will send a request to the Java services. Of couse I don't want that a call blocks my other calls till I receive a response. So, when my PHP controller receives a request this has to be send to the webservice, but I don't want to wait for the response and handle other requests. When I get a response I want to be notified.

Comment: That's actually two questions then, but I'll only comment on the JS->PHP part now ... Waiting for a response on one request shouldn't block other simultaneous requests. If it does, then that's due to a browser limitation, hitting a server-side max_requests limit or something unrelated in your PHP logic (e.g. a session can do that). There are of course ways to work around these conditions, but it's a very broad topic ...

Comment: @Narf Are you sure? By default PHP is single threated..

Comment: It is single threaded, but you don't need threads at all because the httpd (by default) spawns separate processes. In fact, 99% of the time you think threads are the solution, procs are the better solution.

Comment: @Narf So why is eg. `cURL` synchronous? You have to wait till the response before any other code is executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86787/discussion-between-narf-and-guyt).

Answer (score 3):

I can't really make sense of what you are doing ...

- [Asynchronous and Parallel are not interchangeable words.](http://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2015/07/the-universe-is-not-aware.html)
- Threads at the frontend of a web application don't make sense.
- You don't need threads to make many I/O bound tasks concurrent; That is what non-blocking I/O is for (asynchronous concurrency).
- Parallel concurrency seems like overkill here.

Regardless, the reason your requests appear synchronous is the way this constructor is written:

```
function __construct($url){
    $this->url = $url;
    echo 'pooooof request to ' . $this->url . ' sent <br />';
    $request = new Request($this->url);     
    $request->start();
}
```

The `Request` thread will be joined before control is returned to the caller of `__construct` (new) because the variable goes out of scope, and so is destroyed (joining is part of destruction).

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. You've made some really nice libraries! I've tried to clear things up: http://imgur.com/nH2KEcy . 1) JavaScript is executing a `POST` request to a PHP file(eg. `webservice.php?method=blabla`, multiple requests simultaneously). 2) PHP controller will invoke a Java web service. 3) Only after the first long running process has finished, the other requests will invoke the Java web service.. So, that's why I think that PHP is blocking the requests.

Comment: Ohh.. and I've read your post and now I'm realizing that I've mixed things up. Your diagrams about the difference between asynchronous and parallel are very clear. Thank you for that.